# why does the web form submit, even when no content is input?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    function chkname (){
        var ip = document.getElementsById("user");

        if(ip==""){
            alert("please input something!");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="" id="Editor"  method="post" action="wrightchk.php" >
    <input  id="user" type="text"  >
    <input type="submit"  onClick="chkname()">
</form>
```

When the user doesn't input content, the form submits and triggers a redirect.  I want it so that when no content is input, the form alerts, and does not redirect.

Comment: Please work on your English, the title and question are really unclear and I couldn't fix it without changing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `ip` contains a reference to the input element, you need to use the `value` proeprty to get it's content, and the name of the method is `getElementById`, not `getElementsById`:

```
var ip = document.getElementById("user").value;
```

To prevent the form to be posted when the validation fails, you need to return the result from the function in the event:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="return chkname();">
```

You need a `name` attribute on the input field in order for it to be included in the form data when posted:

```
<input id="user" name="user" type="text">
```